# How do I make a State Table in Tabular?

Tags: tables

I want a table that looks similar to this one where `Present State` and `Next State` aren't aligned so close to each other and have their own respective columns.

[image]

The code I have right now:

```
        \begin{tabular}{@{}c c c | c c c@{}} \toprule
            \multicolumn{6}{c}{Present State Next State} \\ \cmidrule(r){1-6}
            A & B & C & A & B & C\\ \midrule
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
            0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
            0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
            0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
            1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
            1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
            1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
            1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
```

What I get from doing the above:

[image]

I've looked into the `tabular` documentation, and there's no explanation for having two columns that have three child columns. Oh, I forgot to mention; I'm using the `booktabs` package.

Comment: Please also keep in mind that horizontal lines from the booktabs package are intended to be used without vertical lines, so you might also want to replace `{@{}c c c | c c c@{}}` with `{@{}c c c c c c@{}}` or `{@{} *{6}{c} @{}}`.

Comment: Replace `\multicolumn{6}{c}{Present State Next State}` with `\multicolumn{3}{@{}c}{Present State} & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Next State}` and `\cmidrule(r){1-6}` with `\cmidrule(r){1-3} \cmidrule(l){4-6}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{*{6}{wc{7mm}}} \toprule
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{Present State} & 
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{Next State} \\ \cmidrule(lr){1-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-6}
    A & B & C & A & B & C\\ \midrule
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: now that is beautiful